# What type is my bike valve, and why can't I pump it up?

Tags: pump, valves

so I've taken some pictures of the valve on my bike tyre (if you zoom out they look clearer...), below. Basically, it's a new bike and I have no experience around these things. The pump I have doesn't fit onto the valve, because it gets stopped by the nut in the middle before it can attach - it's like the pump head is too deep for the valve. Does that make sense? But when I take the metal nut in the middle off, obviously the valve then falls out - but if I hold it in place it can pump the tyre up (showing that the pump is the right type) - but as soon as I remove the pump the valve then falls out and all the air comes out of the tyre again.

I bought the bike in Europe (Slovenia) if that changes anything.

Thanks for any advice on what to do here.

Simon

(My pump is http://washford.scene7.com/is/image/Washford/128234)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, Dunlop/Woods.  I've only seen them like twice.  Probably the least grief is to replace the tube, though I'm not certain you can get a Schrader to fit without reaming the hole a touch, and the Presta should ideally have a bushing.

Comment: This kind of valve has been the only type of valve used for bicycles the last century here in Norway (and I assume most of Europe), only the last decade (or maybe barely two) has the same type of valve as used for car tires become common. It is still commonly used.

Comment: Dunlop valves were common in the Netherlands, Germany and some other non-Latin countries. In places like France or Italy Presta/Sclaverand valves were standard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a ["dunlop"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunlop_valve) valve. Also called ["woods"](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_w.html#woods). I used to see this years ago in BMX bikes. For best results we'd use to have a schrader adapter (google: [dunlop to schrader adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=dunlop%20to%20schrader%20adapter)) so we could inflate with schrader pumps.

[image]

Comment: Sheldon brown says that you can pump these up with a pump setup for presta valves, as the top is the same size as a presta.  If you don't like it, you can always buy a new tube with a standard schrader or presta.  I'm not sure if the hole in the rim is big enough for a schrader (the size is very similar to the dunlop at the base), but a presta tube should work fine.

Comment: Thanks both of you :) Yeah, the valve itself pumps fine with the presta pump I have, it's just the screw thing gets in the way

Comment: For completeness - dunlop/woods uses the same 8mm hole as a schrader valve.  Presta is 6mm by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

These are an old type of valve called a woods valve. you can use a presta valve pump to pump them however it would be easy to change them to Schrader valves as recommended.